# ng-show Displaying all items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

Continue working with angularjs and now having problem with ng-show which on click it show me all hidden data. As I understand, I need to specify ID of clicked item which I want to show, from my example i'm using ng-model which had boolean value and on click it change on true, that's why it's showing all items. Tell me please, how can I show item which I had selected?

```
<div class="list-group" ng-click="SetItemVisible()" ng-repeat="q in feed">
    <a href="" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 ng-model="showItem" class="list-group-item-heading">{{q.title}}</h4>
        <p ng-show="showItem" value="true" class="list-group-item-text">{{q.body}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

And js:

```
$scope.SetItemVisible = function () {
    if (!$scope.showItem) {
        $scope.showItem = true;
    } else {
        $scope.showItem = false;
    }
}

$scope.feed = [];

function getRssItems() {
    rssFeedService.getFeed().then(function (results) {
        $scope.feed = results.data;

    }, function (error) {
        //alert(error.data.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: All `p` elements visibility is binded with single scope variable `showItem`

Comment: ng-show is based on truth value here your "showItem" is always present(i.e) true thats why its showing always.

Comment: How can I specify id of selected item which i want to show?

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do dis by:

```
$scope.feed = [{
    'title': "A",
    'body': "testA body"
  },
  {
    'title': "b",
    'body': "testb body"
  }
  ]
    $scope.showItem = {};
  $scope.SetItemVisible = function (index) {
    $scope.showItem[ index] = true;

  }

 <div class="list-group" ng-click="SetItemVisible($index)" ng-repeat="q in feed track by $index">
<a href="" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 ng-model="showItem[$index]" class="list-group-item-heading">{{q.title}}</h4>
    <p ng-show="showItem[$index]" value="true" class="list-group-item-text">{{q.body}}</p>
</a>
```

For live demo click here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ApI9eb8eQlBdoMUkn8do?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="list-group" ng-click="q.showItem != q.showItem" ng-repeat="q in feed">
    <a href="" class="list-group-item">
        <h4 ng-model="showItem" class="list-group-item-heading">{{q.title}}</h4>
        <p ng-show="q.showItem" value="true" class="list-group-item-text">{{q.body}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your variant not work, because, I think of ng-repeat, the data which he repeats is from 'feed' array which gets from '$http.get' function.

Comment: can you post a sample of the 'feed' array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming following JSON for feed

```
 [
      {
        "title":"test1",
        "body":"test body 1",
        "show":false
      },
      {
        "title":"test2",
        "body":"test body 2",
         "show":false
      }
    ]
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="list-group" ng-repeat="q in feed">
    <a class="list-group-item">
        <h4 ng-click="q.show=!q.show" class="list-group-item-heading">{{q.title}}</h4>
        <p ng-show="q.show" value="true" class="list-group-item-text">{{q.body}}</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.feed = [];

    $http.get('feed.json').then(function (results) {
        $scope.feed = results.data;

    }, function (error) {
        //alert(error.data.message);
    });

});
```

Check out [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qfVgeW5wsyM0Ptt0XEyB?p=preview)